# How to display vertical text (from bottom to top) in the Flutter pdf library?

Tags: flutter, dart, text, containers

`I'm using [this PDF library](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) to generate PDFs in Flutter, which has its own widget system. Im' trying to flip a text widget inside a container to a bottom to up direction and i cant user rotated box widget for that what else is the solution to achieve this adding image here

[image]
this is the code here in pdf package roatedBox is not available
[image]

this is the issue with rotated box
[image]

how to achieve this parent will be container inside text widget as child and string visitor but it should look like this.

i tried rotated box and transform but it doesnt work in pdf creation this is for a pdf printing purpose

```
  Future _writeIntoPdf(String? logo) async {
final pdf = pw.Document();

pdf.addPage(
  pw.Page(
    pageFormat: PdfPageFormat(160, 105),
    build: (pw.Context context) {
      return pw.Container(
          height: 105,
          width: 160,
          decoration: pw.BoxDecoration(border: pw.Border.all(width: 1.0)),
          child: pw.Row(children: [
            pw.Container(
                height: 105,
                width: 20,
                color: PdfColor.fromHex('#f72858'),
                child: pw.RotatedBox(
                  child:pw.Text(
                    'Visitor',
                    style: pw.TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 6,
                    ),) 
                  
                )),))}}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who still tries to figure out a way, [from official example](https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/blob/41cbf8d70dbb5a9ffb830afa43ee93ebd1dc6777/demo/lib/examples/report.dart#L62)

```
Transform.rotateBox(angle: pi/2, child: Text("some sample text"))
```